# Why would giving a 90 degree Radiofrequency pulse to a ZERO longitudinal magnetisation cause zero transverse magnetisation in MRI?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

[image]

Let's imagine in my scenario the (a) in the picture above has no net longitudinal magnetization (therefore 0 longitudinal). Why would giving an 90° RF pulse in my scenario not cause the Protons to precess in PHASE like in (b) and thus give a transverse signal?

Comment: The spins of the proton are either against the external magnetic field or with it, the predominant number of them being parallel to it. When the external magnetic field increases the energy gap between these spins increases. A RF pulse causes the spins to flip in the coupled manner shown in your figure which results in a transverse field. MRI can also be achieved at low earths magnetic field see zero field spectroscopy

Answer (score 1):

If there is no net longitudinal magnetization then that means for each spin in the +z direction there is another spin in the -z direction. When you excite them both by the 90 degree RF pulse the one that started in the +z direction will wind up along +y and the one that started in the -z direction will finish along -y. The +y and -y spins will cancel each other out for no net transverse magnetization.

The spins will precess at the same frequency, but they are not in phase. In fact, they are completely opposed phase.

Comment: But isn't that what happens in a normal scenario even when there is a net longitudinal magnetization?? Half the protons go into anti parallel, the longitudinal magnetization disappears and then for some reason they phase. Whereas here we just skip the first step and go directly to zero longitudinal magnetization but for some reason here they don't phase?? I'm using this video as my basis for this Q https://youtu.be/gLnGNIwCQLo

Comment: No. If there is a net magnetization then it is not half and half. If there is a net magnetization then more than half are aligned.